# Memory Profiling / Memory Leaks in Node.js while running Mocha Tests

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, sails.js, mocha.js

My Node.js Application is showing signs of memory leaks.
I have looked at a few profiling tools, but they all seam to only monitor the application at the launch.

Is there a memory profiling tool which I can run along with mocha unit tests, that can show me which Unit Test's cause the most memory consumption and hence leaks ?

Comment: Have you tried the node inspector?

Comment: Hi kevin, yes, but I can't figure our how to use it with mocha tests.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "signs of memory leaks"?

Comment: The documentation explains how to use it with mocha tests.

Comment: Hi Trott, when I run my mocha tests multiple times, the memory consumption increases with every run and does not go back down after the tests finish. I am monitoring the memory consumption using PM2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's problem with your server.. Try running your server with node app.js  ... Monitor the usage using process.memory usage() ...